# ¿Por qué al colocar un componente de react en una ventana emergente pierde los estilos css?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Tengo un problema al usar una ventana emergente con **react**. La defino así:

```
class Emergente extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.containerEl = document.getElementById('root');
    this.externalWindow = null;
  }
  render() {
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(this.props.children, this.containerEl);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.externalWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=600,height=400,left=200,top=200');
    this.externalWindow.document.body.appendChild(this.containerEl);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.externalWindow.close();
  }
}

export default  Emergente;
```

Y desde el componente app la uso así:

```
const App = () => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Emergente>
                <MenuLateral />
                <MenuSuperior />
                <div id="wrapper">
                    <AdminUsuario />
                </div>
            </Emergente>

        </Provider>

    );
}
```

Los elementos de `<MenuLateral />`,`<MenuSuperior />`,`<AdminUsuario />` son el contenido pero que no tiene el estilo `CSS`. Si lo coloco en una ventana normal me sale así: 
[image: llamandolo como un componente normal]
pero al momento de colocarlo en una ventana emergente me sale así: 
[image: llamandolo en una ventana emergente]

Comment: ¿Que te arroja en la consola de la nueva ventana? (Control+Shift+J). Como sugerencia, podrías usar [`react-new-window`](https://github.com/rmariuzzo/react-new-window)

Comment: @AlterLagos La consola no me arroja nada ya tome esa opcion de react-new-window ahora me carga los estilos css pero no me carga unas imagenes ya estoy depurando a ver que puede ser

Comment: ¿Dónde tienes los estilos metidos? ¿En un stylesheet, en variables? Es por tener contexto y saber por dónde tirar...

Comment: Todos los estilos estan en un stylesheet, el unico estilo que esta en variables es lo que dice: suspendido, activo